# mimic tab switcher ui of Chrome for Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to build a ui that is similar to Tab Switcher in Chrome for Android(see attached image).

I tried StackView, but it was not what I want since it doesn't scroll like tab switcher in chrome.

Does Anyone know any way to implement this UI?
thanks.

[image: Tab Switcher UI of Chrome for Android]

Answer (score -3):

You can make a Tab Switcher from this Library

https://github.com/michael-rapp/ChromeLikeTabSwitcher

This library provides a very easy method to do almost everything a chrome browser does.

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I cannot add comments on someones post. @Daniel